# How to modify a part of string in python

Tags: python

When I execute the following code :

```
file1 = open("sources.conf", "r");
datalist = list(file1.readlines());
datalist[3][32]= "11";
```

I get this error: `'str' object does not support item assignment`. After reading a bit, I discovered that it is not possible to change the string in python. Is there any other work around for this?

Comment: `file1.readlines()` or `list(file1)` is enough..

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do by assigning "11" to  `datalist[3][32]`?

Comment: on datalist[3][32] there is a port number hard codded into the code, I am trying to write a script that will take user input and modify the COMPORT number in the configuration file.  I know for simple things like this I can do it manually by opening the config file, but I wanted to learn python so wanted to do it via a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice the string and reassign it to the same position in your list:

```
datalist[3] = datalist[3][:31] + '11' + datalist[3][33:]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (using slices):

```
datalist[3] = datalist[3][:31] + "11" + datalist[3][33:]
```

Also, Python doesn't use `;` after each statement.

You can also change your string to a list, and back again:

```
temp = list(datalist[3])
temp[32:34] = "11"
datalist[3] = "".join(temp)
```

Comment: `temp[32:34] = "11"` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise You to read line by line and modify string If needed (I am not sure that `readlines()` is the best solution (as It reads whole file into memory)

```
with open("sources.conf", "r") as file1
    datalist = []
    for i, line in  enumerate(file1):
        if i == 3:
            datalist[i] = line[:32] + "11" + line[33:]
        else:
            datalist[i] = line
```

or use `join` methods

```
datalist[i] = ''.join([line[:32], "11", line[33:]])
```